# Is a 4-minute connection enough time to change trains in Utrecht?

Tags: netherlands, train-stations

I have booked a non-refundable train ticket from Frankfurt to Amsterdam. After paying, I found out that I have only 4 minutes to change trains in Utrecht station. Is this sufficient time to make the transfer?

Comment: Could you share the date and the times or train numbers? That would probably allow a more precise answer.

Answer (score 7):

It depends on the arrival and departure track, and how fast you walk, but generally, I'd say yes, unless maybe you have to switch from track 20 to track 1. As far as I'm aware, ICE trains from Germany normally arrive in Utrecht at the same platform as other trains to Amsterdam or next to that platform.

In addition, given you switch trains at Utrecht, that would seem to indicate that you're going to switch to a normal NS intercity train, and normal NS intercity trains do not have reservations, and tickets are generally valid for an entire day. As far as I'm aware, that means that even if you miss your connection, you should be able to take the next train.

Comment: ...which will normally be less than 30 minutes away, usually more like 15 minutes if one is going to one of the major stations.

Comment: @phoog Indeed, between Utrecht Centraal and Amsterdam Centraal, it is - on a weekday in the afternoon - 6 to 14 minutes for the next intercity train.

Comment: And check that your train is indeed not going to the Amsterdam station you need, sometimes the planners have you change trains to win 3 minutes while you could stay in your train.

Comment: @Willeke If the OP is using the ICE (my guess), it might also mean that all seats between Utrecht and Amsterdam were already reserved. However, I believe there are some railworks coming up near Amsterdam, which might mean some trains don't go further than Utrecht.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel, they do not usually reserve seats for the last bit of the journey. Works on the track is a risk.

Comment: I have tried to find this train in the German train planner and I do not find direct trains from Frankfurt to the Netherlands which do not go on to Amsterdam Centraal. But some of the trains for which you need to change in Germany your train goes to Schiphol, Amsterdam Airport and you need to change to a Dutch train to get to Amsterdam Centraal. On the other hand, if you need to be at the airport you will need to change somewhere as your train will not go there. In any case, your options are many as this is the line with about the most trains in the Netherlands.